# XMLWorkerHelper loses text not between tags

Tags: itext

I've been using XMLWorkerHelper to add formatted text, inputted on pages via a rich text editor, to PDFs. I've noticed that sometimes not all text was rendered in the PDF. Apparently XMLWorkerHelper drops text not between HTML tags. 
Is this correct behavior?

I've written a JUnit test case that shows the problem:

```
public class XMLWorkerTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        String fileName = "itext_test_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf";
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        document.open();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

        String s1 = "not between tags<b>between tags</b>not between tags";
        addHtml(paragraph, s1);
        // NOT OK: 'not between tags' missing twice

        paragraph.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        String s2 ="<span>" + s1 + "</span>";
        addHtml(paragraph, s2);
        // OK

        document.add(paragraph);
        document.close();
    }

    private void addHtml(final Paragraph paragraph, String html) throws IOException {
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(new ElementHandler() {
            @Override
            public void add(Writable writable) {
                if (writable instanceof WritableElement) {
                    for (Element element : ((WritableElement) writable).elements()) {
                        paragraph.add(element);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()), Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

We're using version 5.5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. Your html should have a root tag otherwise it's not really html. Just because the text shows in a browser doesn't mean that is well formed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Our RT editor component is really letting us down here. It doesn't always give correct HTML. We're already planning on replacing it with CKEditor. For now we'll wrap the strings with <span> tags.